# Infinite loop and strange characters with: while (chars = fgetc(map) != EOF)

Tags: c, infinite-loop, eof, operator-precedence, getchar

I'm trying to read a file (map.txt) with fopen() and fgetc(), but I'm getting an infinite loop and strange characters as output. I've tried different conditions, different possibilities, and the loop is always infinite, as if EOF did not exist.

I want to create a map-tile basic system with text files (Allegro), and to do so I need to learn how to READ them. So I'm trying to simply read the file and print its contents, character by character.

```
void TileSystem() {

    theBitmap = al_load_bitmap("image.png"); // Ignore it.  

    float tileX = 0.0; // Ignore it.    
    float tileY = 0.0; // Ignore it.    
    float tileXFactor = 0.0; // Ignore it.  
    float tileYFactor = 0.0; // Ignore it.  

    al_draw_bitmap( theBitmap, 0, 0, 0 ); // Ignore it. 

    FILE *map;
    map = fopen( "map.txt", "r");

    int loopCondition = 1;
    int chars;

    while ( loopCondition == 1 && ( chars = fgetc( map ) != EOF ) ) {
            putchar( chars );
        }
}
```

The content of map.txt is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

And what I get of output is an infinite loop of:

```
???????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????...
```

But what I see on terminal is:

[image: EOF BUG]

Well, I just need to read all the chars, and the compiler needs to recognize the end of the file correctly.

Comment: Today's tip: Parenthesize everything!  Relying on esoteric rules of operator precedence is a recipe for tears.

Comment: BTW: the loopcondition is loop-invariant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
chars = fgetc( map ) != EOF
```

should be

```
(chars = fgetc(map) ) != EOF
```

This is a complete working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *fp = fopen("test.c","rt");
  int c;
  while ( (c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF) {
    putchar(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, the bugged characters disappeared with this, but the infinite loop is still there. I can't understand why... It keeps printing 123456789123456789123456789123456789 endlessly. It does not recognize the EOF.

Answer (score 1):

```
chars = fgetc( map ) != EOF
```

`!=` has higher precedence than `=`, you probably wanted to do something like this instead: `(chars = fgetc( map )) != EOF`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
chars = fgetc( map ) != EOF
```

Is getting executed like this:

```
chars = (fgetc( map ) != EOF)
```

So you should add parentheses like this:

```
(chars = fgetc( map )) != EOF
```

Comment: I did this (I fixed now), but the infinite loop is still there.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( loopCondition == 1 && ( chars = fgetc( map ) != EOF ) ) {
```

doesn't look right... Have you tried:

```
while ( loopCondition == 1 && ( ( chars = fgetc( map ) ) != EOF ) ) {
```

Comment: I did this (I fixed now), but the infinite loop is still there.

Comment: you must be calling the TileSystem() function in a loop then... try adding "putchar('\n')" at the beginning of the function: if you get multiple lines of "123456789", then TileSystem() is being called repeatedly; if you still get a single line of "123456789123456789...", then I've no idea :)